# Inflate exception on 'recycleview' missing scroll bar drawable on some devices?

Tags: android

Not really sure how to explain this one...

http://crashes.to/s/69f1e7da266

```
Fatal Exception android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView
```

Does not seem to be code related more, android/device fragmentation related, any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it got re-thrown a few times. If you scroll down you'll find

> Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException
>   res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png

to

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>   File res/drawable-hdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x0

It looks like the apk may have been installed on removable storage that became unavailable before it tried retrieving the drawable. To check for this you'll need to either register for the intents or occasionally check the status of the sd-card.

Depending on your app's size you may be able to cache some of the needed resources just in case.

[Storage Options | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

`Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE`
`Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE`

`Environment.getExternelStorageState()`